How should I fasten a deck ledger to a concrete block wall?
I'm trying to rebuild our deck. How do I attach a 2X8 board to a 8 inch block concrete wall? What size concrete screw do I need?

are you screwing in the block or true the block

What do you mean when you say "rebuild?"  Are you replacing a board that's already screwed to the block wall?

I've revised your title since your assumption that screws are the right method is faulty.

Do you have access to the interior of the wall?

Many jurisdictions have outlawed screw attachment for ledgers and beams, be it into a wooden rim joist or into concrete block. My experience tells me that screws (such as Tapcons) are woefully inadequate for this purpose. I might trust sleeve anchors into poured concrete, but not ungrouted block. There's too much potential for blowout due to tension.
I suggest through-bolts with substantial backing plates. 3" x 3" in 1/4" steel would be appropriate. You'd want to put the bolts through adjacent to a block rib so you aren't risking collapse upon tightening.
You may also find purpose-built hardware from the likes of Simpson Strong-Tie, but a quick search didn't turn up anything for this case.
Your best course of action is to contact your local inspection office (or one in a nearby community if you're way rural) and ask what they're looking for, regardless of whether you intend to file a permit. At least you know you'll be in compliance.
